# What does the program counter do?

Tags: cpu

I was browsing the architecture of a simple CPU but there is one thing a cannot understand. Why is there data from the ALU going to the program counter and what is that data for?

Answer (score 11):

Since this is a simple CPU, it's almost certainly to compute branch targets. Branch instructions typically represent the location to branch to as a small signed number to add to the program counter. The reason for this is that conditional branches almost always occur within a procedure or function, so it makes sense to encode them as an offset, which uses fewer bits.

In "real" CPUs, another common use case is to support [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

Comment: In your second paragraph, you mean to provide PC-relative addressing modes and/or address-generation into registers?  That's not necessary to support PIC, but it helps efficiency.  e.g. 32-bit x86 can only read the program counter by running a `call` instruction (which pushes a return address), then reading that memory (e.g. with `pop` into a register).  This sucks a lot for PIC/PIE code: every function that accesses static data needs to find its own address and address the GOT relative to that, which is why x86-64 introduced RIP-relative addressing for data load/store, not just jumps/calls.

Comment: Many modern RISC ISAs have an instruction like `adrp` that sets a GP-integer register = PC + something, with page granularity so it can reach far (scaling the immediate offset).  See [What are the semantics of ADRP and ADRL instructions in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41906688) for details for AArch64.  So that's a specific real-world example of what I think you're talking about in that 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

The program counter is a special processor register pointing to the next instruction to be fetched from memory and executed. When executing a non-branching instruction, the CPU increases the PC by 1 (or the size of instructions). Branching means assigning a new value to the program counter. Addresses to branch to are rarely absolute - usually they are relative to the current position, or to the beginning of a code segment. Therefore, such values need to be able to come from the ALU.

Comment: Branch addresses can also come from a dedicated address generator, but an address generator and an ALU are similar enough that a simple CPU is likely to have just the ALU.

Comment: @Mark: yup, one reason for not sharing is in a pipelined design where an adder is busy computing the next PC to fetch, in parallel with executing an earlier instruction that might be ALU.  e.g. a MIPS with the pipelining between stages taken out is even simpler to look at: [Mips datapath procedure for executing an AND instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23305368)

Comment: Just as a comment about this, 8-bit micros of the 1970s and 1980s did not use the "main" ALU for incrementing the PC because data was typically 8-bit but the PC was 16-bit. The MOS 6502 had dedicated PC increment logic, the Zilog Z80 had a separate 16+8 bit adder which was also used for branch and index register calculations, and the Intel 8080 had a separate piece of logic that was used for increment and decrement operations on general registers as well as the PC. I suspect that using the "main" ALU for incrementing the PC has always been rare.